# Are underscore required for new querys with hibernate and spring boot?

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm discovering the implementation of hibernate + spring boot and I was wondering if underscores were important for our query when our table's column name has one.

For instance a basic query would be

```
List<User> findByEmailAddressAndLastname(String emailAddress, String lastname);
```

which would turn into

```
select u from User u where u.emailAddress = ?1 and u.lastname = ?2
```

But if my table has an underscore, for instance "id_meeting", would I need to write

```
List<User> findById_Meeting(long id);
```

to turn it into

```
select u from User u where u.id_meeting = ?1
```

or is is actually the parameter name that is used and I'd instead need to write

```
List<User> findByIdMeeting(long id_meeting);
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not worry about underscore in table names - the ORM provider do the name conversion yourself.

Regarding your query example - its [JPQL](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_01/ejb3_langref.html) query there you operate the entities, not tables - you are using names of your classes.

Concerning the repository method names - according to [Spring Data JPA documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions) underscore is used to implicitly separate direct and nested properties of the entity.

Comment: Then how can I specify my table's column name with an underscore? The table's column name is imposed to me and I'm not sure I have the right to edit it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also found out that it is possible to use a @Column(name=) while doing some more search.

Comment: @Kpo Yes, of cause )) I recommend you to read [Hibernate User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html)...